# Не могу понять, как подружить две функции? Как передать значения? Пишу свое первое задание по питону

Tags: python

Как передать значения переменных из 1 функции во вторую? Обе функции часть программы. Должны выполняться последовательно. Пробовал делать через global, но говорят этого надо избегать.

```
def foo1():
        a=int(input('введите первое число'))
        b=int(input('введите второе число'))
        return(a,b)
def foo2():
        c=(a+b)
        return (c)
```

Comment: Ничего не понятно. Что значит подружить? Значения какие откуда куда зачем? Что вы вообще пытаетесь сделать и зачем вам две функции?

Comment: Во-первых, вторая функция должна в принципе принимать значения: `def foo2(a, b):` Во-вторых, чтобы вторая функция заработала, её кто-то должен вызывать и при вызове передавать нужные значения: `return foo2(a, b)`

Comment: @andreymal, не обязательно же. Например, можно использовать переменные типа global:-) Что, конечно, является ужасным стилем, но технически возможно.

Comment: @Сергей поэтому давайте про global лучше вообще не вспоминать)

Comment: Не ругайтесь, но я не понял как вызвать foo2 со  значениями из foo1. Первая возвратит 2 числа. Как их передать.

Comment: Открыть учебник и почитать главу по функции. Здесь не сайт по объяснению основ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Антон, до чтения основ обязательно упорядочите понимание, что вы делаете и зачем. Сама формулировка "как вызвать foo2 со значениями из foo1. Первая возвратит 2 числа. Как их передать." совершенно неверна. Вам надо либо вызывать foo2 из foo1 и **передать** туда параметры, либо вызвать foo1 из foo2 и **получить** их. Поместил пример ниже, иначе долго читать будете. Но обязательно прочитайте про функции внимательно, особенно, зачем нужно передавать параметры, а зачем возвращать их.

```
def foo1():
    # добавил по 2 символа для эстетики
    a=int(input('введите первое число: ')) 
    b=int(input('введите второе число: ')) 
    return(a,b)

def foo2():
    # добавил вызов
    a,b=foo1()                           
    c=(a+b)
    return (c)
```

И второй вариант добавил:

```
def foo1():
    # добавил по 2 символа для эстетики
    a =int(input('введите первое число: '))
    b=int(input('введите второе число: '))
    # добавил вызов
    return (foo2(a,b))
# добавил аргументы
def foo2(a,b):
    c=(a+b)
    return (c)
```

Comment: Антон, если ответ был полезным, его можно отметить плюсом (нажать треугольник вверх слева от вопроса). Если ответ полностью решил задачу - принять ответ (нажать на галку под треугольниками слева). И сообщите (через @ для надёжности), если после прочтения главы по функциям что-то в этом примере осталось неясным.

Answer (score 1):

Например, так:

```
a, b = foo1()
c = foo2(a, b)
```

Только нужно написать саму функцию `foo2` так, чтобы они принимала эти две переменные `a` и `b` как параметры функции. Да, в питоне в принципе можно этого и не делать, `foo2` и так увидит эти переменные, поскольку они будут глобальными, но это плохой стиль, функции должны полагаться только на те переменные, которые они получают в явном виде как параметры. Для этого есть много причин, слишком долго их тут все объяснять.

Comment: Спасибо. Пошел разбираться.